# The exact meaning of "John's paintings of his cat were auctioned"

Tags: possessives

Could it be true:

- John's paintings of his cat were auctioned. = Some paintings ***made and owned*** by John depicting his cat were auctioned.

Comment: It's ambiguous.  "John's paintings" could be painted by John, could be owned by John, could be both.

Comment: The possessive in English (and many other language) does not always speak of pure ownership: *Napolean's defeat at Waterloo* is not a defeat that Napolean owned in the sense of a possession. So, since this site is for advanced users of English, I highly encourage you to do research on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It could be true (paintings not painting)

But a safer assumption is that John is deceased or had his property siezed by debt collectors, for him to be parting with mementos of his beloved pet.